# How to prevent an object from stretching after rotation?

Tags: three.js

How to prevent an object from being stretched after being rotated inside another object that has some scale?

In general, I want the child to behave as if the parent has a size of 1, 1, 1,
and I don't want to create a group for the parent and for the child.

---

A few letters for the system to accept the question

---

```
import * as THREE from 'three';
import { OrbitControls } from 'three/addons/controls/OrbitControls.js';

// Renderer

const renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({
  alpha: false,
  antialias: true,
  stencil: false,
  depth: false
});

document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

const scene = new THREE.Scene();
const camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera();
camera.position.z = 10;

new OrbitControls(camera, renderer.domElement)

// Parent

const parentGeometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry(1, 1, 1);
const parentMaterial = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({ color: "tomato" });
const parent = new THREE.Mesh(parentGeometry, parentMaterial);
parent.scale.set(3, 0.5, 3)
scene.add(parent);

// Child

const childGeometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry(1, 1, 1);
const childMaterial = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({ color: "lightblue" });
const child = new THREE.Mesh(childGeometry, childMaterial);
parent.add(child);

child.scale.x = 1 / parent.scale.x;
child.scale.y = 1 / parent.scale.y;
child.scale.z = 1 / parent.scale.z;

// ???

child.rotation.x = Math.PI / 4;

function resize() {
  const width = document.documentElement.clientWidth;
  const height = window.innerHeight;

  camera.aspect = width / height;
  camera.fov = 55
  camera.updateProjectionMatrix();

  renderer.setPixelRatio(Math.min(2, devicePixelRatio));
  renderer.setSize(width, height);
}

window.addEventListener("resize", resize);
resize();


function tick(t) {
  requestAnimationFrame(tick);
  renderer.render(scene,camera);
}

requestAnimationFrame(tick);
```

Comment: code from the question: https://jsfiddle.net/pub0rca7/

Comment: Why do you not want to use a group? This seems like the simplest solution.